# Unable to install Visual Studio 2017 community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2017, failed-installation

Upon installation I get a message box stating: "Setup Operation Failed". When I view the log it contains: 
[2034:000c][2017-03-07T15:50:03] Error 0x80004003: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.InstanceRepository.GetInstance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.d__27.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to go on. Please run http://aka.ms/vscollect.exe then attach %TEMP%\vslogs.zip to a new issue you should file using the Feedback tool. In the Visual Studio Installer, click the feedback button in the upper-right corner.